# Service Return Empty Lists To Api Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I am working in service fabrics micro services , where i need to fetch record for an object. when I send request to API , it shows me empty lists while rest of the data is in place. while debugging I came to know that before returning to API controller my service object has all the data expected i.e lists has data , but when it comes back to web API the lists are empty. 
After searching for solution over web I came to know that every time a request is to the API the lists are recreated , so it shows empty result. Any Solutions to come out of this problem?
Here is my piece of code.
The following Is the Web Api Method.

```
[HttpGet()]
[Route("edit/{readingListId}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<GetReadingListDTO>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<GetReadingListDTO>), (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetReadingListById(int readingListId)
{
    try
    {
        var readingList = await this._readingListService.GetReadingListByIdAsync(readingListId);
        return Ok(readingList);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this._logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        return BadRequest();
    }

}
```

The following Is the Service Method.

```
 public async Task<Domain.ReadingList> GetReadingListByIdAsync(int readingListId)
        {
            try
            {
                Domain.ReadingList  readingList = await _repository.FindById(readingListId);
                return readingList;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Moreover , This Is My Entity.

```
    public class ReadingList : EntityBase, IAggregateRoot, IAggregateCreateRoot, IAggergateUpdateRoot, IAggregateDeleteRoot
    {
        public ReadingList()
        {

            this.Items = new List<ReadingListItem>();
            this.Assignees = new List<ReadingListAssignee>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public EntityType EntityTypeId { get; set; }
        public int EntityId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime CompletionDate { get; set; }
        public int ReminderDay { get; set; }
        public string ReminderDayType { get; set; }
        public bool  SendReminder { get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        public int? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }

        public int? DeletedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }
        public bool? Deleted { get; set; }


        public List<ReadingListItem> Items { get; private set; }
        public List<ReadingListAssignee> Assignees { get; private set; }
}
```

Thanks!

**Edited**

The Issue Was Resolved , By Simply Changing The dll Versions.One Of The Service Had And Old Version While The Version Was Updated In The Other One.
Thanks For The Help.

Comment: It seems that the returning value Domain.ReadingList doesn't look like what you indicated in controller annotation  [ProducesResponseType]: List<GetReadingListDTO> . Can you try to debug and try to return a static test List<GetReadingListDTO> ? or just change your annotation for Domain.ReadingList ?

Comment: Have you just debugged you code with breakpoints and seen whether your readingService methods returns anything when given an existing Id ?

Comment: @Pac0 yes I have Debugged My Service Code, While returning It Has All The Expected Data.

Comment: @Pac0 Even by Changing The Response Type From GetReadingListdto to reading list didnt make any affect. still getting empty lists

Comment: What HTTP status code the API returns when you call it?

Comment: It returns OK 200 ... I have Even Tried It Using Postman Too @AlexeyAndrushkevich

Comment: I remember having to use [DataContract] (on class) and [DataMember] (on every property that I want to go out of my API). Could you try that on your ReadingList class ?

Comment: @Pac0 yes , i have tried that too... even that too didn't help me out.